# how to keep the block format the way it is?

Tags: clang-format

I use clang-format to format my code.
Everything works fine except for the block code, as you can see the code below, the failure block has indent 4 space ...

```
_loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{
    [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup];
} failure:^(NSString *errorString) {
    [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail];
}];
```

after format:

```
_loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{
  [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup];
}
    failure:^(NSString *errorString) {
      [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail];
    }];
```

How can I customize my clang-format config?

Here is my config:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM  
IndentWidth: 4  
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach  
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true  
IndentCaseLabels: true    
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4   
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ColumnLimit: 0  
AlignTrailingComments: true  
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true 
SpacesInParentheses: false  
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's four years later now, but possibly somebody would like to see an answer to this question anyway...

---

Just to be sure, your question title seems to ask how to prevent `clang-format` from modifying a block of code. If that's all you want, you can do that by putting `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` around that code. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code) for more details.

---

You don't mention what version of `clang-format` you're using, and unfortunately your code is formatted differently by different versions of `clang-format`. (I explored these versions using the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/)).

- Version 3.5.2 gives:

  ```
  _loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{
      [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup];
  } failure:^(NSString *errorString) { [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail]; }];
  ```
- Version 3.6.0 gives:

  ```
  _loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{
    [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup];
  } failure:^(NSString *errorString) {
    [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail];
  }];
  ```
- Versions 3.7.0 through 6.0.1 give:

  ```
  _loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{
      [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup];
  }
      failure:^(NSString *errorString) {
          [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail];
      }];
  ```
- Version 7.0.1 through 10.0.0 give:

  ```
  _loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation
      tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{
          [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup];
      }
      failure:^(NSString *errorString) {
          [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail];
      }];
  ```

So you were perhaps using something like version 6.0.0, and simply upgrading to a newer version of `clang-format` might give you formatting that you would like better.

---

In addition, you may also want to set the style option `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true` (see the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for details). For `clang-format` version 10.0.0, your code would then look like this:

```
_loginOperation = [CheckTIMPreparation
    tim_CheckPreparationSuccess:^{ [weakSelf checkIsJoinGroup]; }
    failure:^(NSString *errorString) { [weakSelf showloginingViewWithFail]; }];
```